# Speeding up my current Code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I first want to apologize for dumping a lot of code into here. I was assigned to build a planning screen wherein I could pull corresponding information regarding Sales, Production, and Inventory. As a Preface to all of this, this code works for me and does exactly what I need it to do.

The problem, however, is the amount of time it takes to run. Originally, it was taking about 5-7 minutes, but I have been able to reduce it to 1-2 minutes depending on the computer being used. I have tried changing multiple things, and can not reduce the time more.

```
Sub FillInventoryAcross()
'This code is the formulas for the Total Inventory, Sales, and Production Data. Just addition formulas.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
    strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(C15,C20,C25,C30,C35,C40)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=SUM(C16,C21,C26,C31,C36,C41)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=SUM(C18,C23,C28,C33,C38,C43)"

    .Range("C11:W11").formula = strFormulas(1)
    .Range("C11:W11").FillRight
    .Range("C12:W12").formula = strFormulas(2)
    .Range("C12:W12").FillRight
    .Range("C13:W13").formula = strFormulas(3)
    .Range("C13:W13").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub FillInventoryPerLocation()
'This code will fill in the inventory per location. It will add up all of the sales, movement and production per plant along with the prior days inventory.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 12) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L95"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0))+SUM(C16:C19)+C46,0),0)"
strformula(2) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L90"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C21:C24),0)"
strformula(3) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L91"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C26:C29),0)"
strformula(4) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L93"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C31:C34),0)"
strformula(5) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""L94"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C36:C39),0)"
strformula(6) = "=IFERROR(IF(TRIM(Inventori!$D:$D)=""A78"",INDEX(Inventori!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)),0)+SUM(C41:C44),0)"
strformula(7) = "=C15+Sum(D16:D19)+D46"
strformula(8) = "=C20+sum(D21:D24)"
strformula(9) = "=C25+sum(D26:D29)"
strformula(10) = "=C30+sum(D31:D34)"
strformula(11) = "=C35+sum(D36:D39)"
strformula(12) = "=C40+sum(D41:D44)"
.Range("C15").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C20").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C25").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C30").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C35").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C40").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("D15:W15").formula = strformula(7)
.Range("D15:W15").FillRight
.Range("D20:W20").formula = strformula(8)
.Range("D20:W20").FillRight
.Range("D25:W25").formula = strformula(9)
.Range("D25:W25").FillRight
.Range("D30:W30").formula = strformula(10)
.Range("D30:W30").FillRight
.Range("D35:W35").formula = strformula(11)
.Range("D35:W35").FillRight
.Range("D40:W40").formula = strformula(12)
.Range("D40:W40").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfSales()
'This code will pull up all of the sales information for a product. Just a Sumif looking up information that matches Date/SKU. After the code is in the starting cell, it is then dragged accross for all of the other dates.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L95"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L90"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L91"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L93"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L94"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""A78"",Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN"")*-1)"
.Range("C16:W16").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C16:W16").FillRight
.Range("C21:W21").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C21:W21").FillRight
.Range("C26:W26").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C26:W26").FillRight
.Range("C31:W31").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C31:W31").FillRight
.Range("C36:W36").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C36:W36").FillRight
.Range("C41:W41").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C41:W41").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfMovement()
'This code works in a similar way to the prior code, but looks to match Date/SKU to find product movement.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""95"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L95""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""90"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L90""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""91"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L91""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""93"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L93""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""94"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""L94""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$O$1:$O$200000,""78"")-SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C8,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VT"",Sales!$B$1:$B$200000,""A78""))"
.Range("C17:W17").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C17:W17").FillRight
.Range("C22:W22").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C22:W22").FillRight
.Range("C27:W27").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C27:W27").FillRight
.Range("C32:W32").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C32:W32").FillRight
.Range("C37:W37").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C37:W37").FillRight
.Range("C42:W42").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C42:W42").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SumIfProduction()
'This code yet again works like the other two codes, but for production.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 6) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P95""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P90""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P91""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P93""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""P94""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Production!$Q$1:$Q$100000,Production!$B$1:$B$100000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!C$8,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$I$1:$I$100000,""A78""))"
.Range("C18:W18").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("C18:W18").FillRight
.Range("C23:W23").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("C23:W23").FillRight
.Range("C28:W28").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("C28:W28").FillRight
.Range("C33:W33").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("C33:W33").FillRight
.Range("C38:W38").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("C38:W38").FillRight
.Range("C43:W43").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("C43:W43").FillRight
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub DailySalesHistory()
'This code works to look up the Sales History by day for a given product. Takes each starting Monday and will add a day to it accross until Sunday, then the next week starts. Does the Date/SKU thing like the other sections. It then multiplies the end value by -1 to make the sales values positive, as the user would like to see them as.
Call SpeedUp
Dim strformula(1 To 7) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inventory")
strformula(1) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(2) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+1,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(3) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+2,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(4) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+3,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(5) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+4,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(6) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+5,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
strformula(7) = "=(SUMIFS(Sales!$I$1:$I$200000,Sales!$D$1:$D$200000,CONCATENATE(Inventory!$B51+6,Inventory!$M$3),Sales!$AD$1:$AD$200000,""VN""))"
.Range("D51").formula = strformula(1)
.Range("D51:D108").FillDown
.Range("E51").formula = strformula(2)
.Range("E51:E108").FillDown
.Range("F51").formula = strformula(3)
.Range("F51:F108").FillDown
.Range("G51").formula = strformula(4)
.Range("G51:G108").FillDown
.Range("H51").formula = strformula(5)
.Range("H51:H108").FillDown
.Range("I51").formula = strformula(6)
.Range("I51:I108").FillDown
.Range("J51").formula = strformula(7)
.Range("J51:J108").FillDown
End With
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub WeeklySalesHistory()
'This code will take all of the valuse returned in the prior code and add them together. This will give the user the total sales of a product for a given week.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K51").formula = "=SUM(D51:J51)"
Range("K51:K108").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub TopDaysoftheWeek()
'This code will bring up the days of the week for three weeks. Starts with Sunday and ends with Saturday. First formula finds the Sunday, the other formulas just adds 1 to the day.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C8").formula = "=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("D8").formula = "=C8+1"
Range("D8:W8").FillRight
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub InventoryInfo()
'This code runs vlookups on the inputted SKU number to pull up corresponding information. If the cell is blank, it will tell the user what will come up. If there is an error, it will reflect that.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""SKU Number"",INDEX(ItemMaster!$B:$B,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Product Name"",IF(ISTEXT(INDEX(ItemMaster!$D:$D,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))),INDEX(ItemMaster!$D:$D,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)),INDEX(ItemMaster!$C:$C,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("F6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Pieces Per Case in"",INDEX(ItemMaster!$I:$I,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0)))&"" pieces"""
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("I6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Pieces Per Case in "",(ROUND(INDEX(ItemMaster!$J:$J,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))*35.274,2)))&"" Oz"""""
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L6").FormulaArray = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Date of Last Run"",MAX(IF(Production!$H:$H=Inventory!$M$3,Production!$N:$N)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("N6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Line of Last Run"",INDEX(Production!$E:$E,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Production!$H:$H,0)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("P6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Allergen Codes"",""Codes: ""&$AI$5)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("Q6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$6)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$7)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("S6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$8)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("T6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$9)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("U6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$10)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("V6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$11)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W6").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",$AI$12)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("E10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Cases Per Dough"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE($M$3),CPD!$A$1:$D$381,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(NUMBERVALUE($M$3),CPD!$A$1:$D$381,2,FALSE)))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("J10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Lines Product Was Run On"",""Lines: ""&$AO$5)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO6),ISNA(AO6)),"""",AO6))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO7),ISNA(AO7)),"""",AO7))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("M10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO8),ISNA(AO8)),"""",AO8))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("N10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),"""",IF(OR(ISERR(AO9),ISNA(AO9)),"""",AO9))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("O10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Average Cases Sold Per Week"", SUM(K56:K67)/12)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Average Cases Sold Per Day"", $O$10/7)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("U10").formula = "=IF(ISBLANK($M$3),""Days of Inventory Remaining"",(INDEX(Inventori!$F:$F,MATCH(Inventory!$M$3,Inventori!$B:$B,0)))/R10)"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub HiddenFormulas()
'This code runs some of the hidden formulas used to calculate and find factors for the inventory screen. The user will not be allowed to see or interact with them.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF5").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$K:$K,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF6").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$L:$L,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF7").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$M:$M,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF8").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$N:$N,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF9").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$O:$O,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF10").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$P:$P,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF11").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$Q:$Q,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AF12").formula = "=INDEX(ItemMaster!$R:$R,MATCH($M$3,ItemMaster!$B:$B,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI5").formula = "=IF($AF$5=""X"",""O"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI6").formula = "=IF(AF6=""X"",""A"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI7").formula = "=IF(AF7=""X"",""B"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI8").formula = "=IF(AF8=""X"",""C"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI9").formula = "=IF(AF9=""X"",""AB"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI10").formula = "=IF(AF10=""X"",""AC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI11").formula = "=IF(AF11=""X"",""BC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AI12").formula = "=IF(AF12=""X"",""ABC"","""")"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AL5").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(Production!$E:$E, SMALL(IF(Inventory!$M$3=Production!$H:$H, ROW(Production!$H:$H)-ROW($A$1)+1), ROW(1:1)))"
Range("AL5:AL554").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO5").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO4,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO6").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO5,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO7").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO6,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Invnetory").Range("AO8").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO7,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("AO9").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($AL$5:$AL$554, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($AO$4:AO8,$AL$5:$AL$554), 0))"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub BottomDaysoftheWeek()
'This code runs with TopDaysoftheWeek. Thile that code will pull up the date of each day, this code will convert that into the name of the day.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("C9").formula = "=TEXT(C8,""ddd"")"
Range("C9:W9").FillRight
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryByMonth()
'This code finds the months for Sales History. It will find the month ahead of the current month all the way until a year prior.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L51").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L53").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L55").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L57").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-3)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L59").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-4)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L61").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-5)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L63").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-6)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L65").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-7)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L67").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-8)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L69").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-9)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L71").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-10)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L73").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-11)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L75").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-12)+1"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L77").formula = "=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-13)+1"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryWeeks()
'This code finds the weeks of sales history. The first formula takes the first date of the inventory section and adds 6 weeks to it. The following formula just decreases the week by a week until the end of the table.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B51").formula = "=(C8+42)-WEEKDAY(C8,3)"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B52").formula = "=B51-7"
Range("B52:B108").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub SalesHistoryMonthlyCalculations()
'This code calculates the sales history by month. It works by adding together all of the weekly sales history to the left of these formulas based on if the weeks are within the corresponding month. This formula is a little iffy, where it works on a beginning of the week basis (i.e. 5/28-6/4 counts as May, not May and June). Aside form that, works really well. May need to rework this formula.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L52").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L51,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L51,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L54").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L53,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L53,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L56").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L55,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L55,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L58").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L57,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L57,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L60").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L59,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L59,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L62").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L61,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L61,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L64").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L63,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L63,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L66").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L65,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L65,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L68").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L67,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L67,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L70").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L69,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L69,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L72").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L71,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L71,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L74").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L73,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L73,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L76").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L75,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L75,0))"
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("L78").formula = "=SUMIFS(K51:K108,B51:B108,"">=""&L77,B51:B108,""<=""&EOMONTH(L77,0))"
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ProductionHistoryInfo()
'This code is all of the formulas regarding Production History. Finds Cases, Doughs, and Line product was run on. Also has the yield formulas (cases/doughs).
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("Q52").FormulaArray = "=IF(OR(($O52)="""",$O52=DATE(1900,1,0)),"""",INDEX(Production!$R:$R,MATCH(CONCATENATE(Inventory!$O52,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$B:$B,0)))"
Range("Q52:Q104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("R52").formula = "0"
Range("R52:R104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("S52").FormulaArray = "=IF(OR(($O52)="""",$O52=DATE(1900,1,0)),"""",INDEX(Production!$E:$E,MATCH(CONCATENATE(Inventory!$O52,Inventory!$M$3),Production!$B:$B,0)))"
Range("S52:S104").FillDown
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("T52").formula = "=IF(ISERR(Q52/R52),"""",Q52/R52)"
Range("T52:T104").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ProductionHistoryDates()
'This code finds the dates that a given product was run on. Uses an array function to look up dates of production based on matching SKU numbers. Most volatile function in this section. Can only lookup/match up to 20,000 values, which could be problematic. May need some editing done based on how actual tables are set up. Goes from oldest to newest, which may also be a problem.
Call SpeedUp
Worksheets("Inventory").Range("O52").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(OFFSET(Production!$H$1:$H$100000,SMALL(IF(Production!$H$1:$H$100000=Inventory!$M$3,ROW(Production!$H$1:$H$100000)-ROW(INDEX(Production!$H$1:$H$100000,1,1))),ROW()-51),COLUMN()-9),"""")"
Range("O52:O104").FillDown
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub BorderFixer()
'This code was created after I discovered that some of these vba formulas will break the borders I made after running. Its only purpose is to fill in those broken borders and fix them to look like how they looked before.

With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W10").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.ColorIndex = 2
End With

  With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("W7:W43").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
 .Weight = xlThin
 .ColorIndex = 2
 End With

 With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("B108:K108").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
 .Weight = xlThin
 .ColorIndex = 2
 End With

 With Worksheets("Inventory").Range("K108").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Weight = xlThin
.ColorIndex = 2
End With
End Sub

Sub ResetInventory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to inventory, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
 Call SpeedUp
 Call InventoryInfo
 Call TopDaysoftheWeek
 Call BottomDaysoftheWeek
 Call SumIfSales
 Call SumIfMovement
 Call SumIfProduction
 Call FillInventoryPerLocation
 Call FillInventoryAcross
 Call BorderFixer
 Call CPD
 Call SpeedDown
 End Sub

Sub ResetSalesHistory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to sales history, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
Call SpeedUp
Call SalesHistoryWeeks
Call DailySalesHistory
Call WeeklySalesHistory
Call SalesHistoryByMonth
Call SalesHistoryMonthlyCalculations
Call BorderFixer
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub ResetProductionHistory()
'This code is made to run only if the user manages to unlock all of the cells on this sheet and start deleting the formulas I added. Once clicked, this code will: deactivate all of Excel's functions, run all of the prior codes related to production history, run the border fixer to repair broken borders, and reactivate Excel's functions. While it runs fast and effectively, has a chance to break the worksheet. If so, click fix frozen cells. Will return error if the user tries to run this while sheets are protected.
Call SpeedUp
Call ProductionHistoryDates
Call ProductionHistoryInfo
Call BorderFixer
Call SpeedDown
End Sub

Sub InventoryPrintPreview()
'This code is made to show the users a print preview of what the worksheet will look like. I already made the print areas for the three tables on this sheet. User can change margins or format.
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
Worksheets("Inventory").PrintPreview
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If this works without issues, and you're just looking to make it more efficient, then I suggest instead posting this to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). At the very least, you should definitely look in to creating `For` loops.

Comment: Am I the only one who are real curious what this speedup sub is?

Comment: ^I am curious as well, can you share?

Comment: @Andreas I have seen a few people use a sub called `SpeedUp` to set things like `ScreenUpdating`, `Calculation`, etc.  Some versions of it have a `True` / `False` parameter to indicate whether they are setting the values or switching them back, but the OP seems to be using a version called `SpeedDown` to switch them back.

Comment: @YowE3K If that is the case then there is loads of time to save (probably) by not speeding up and down all the time. Just keep that turbo button on your 486 pushed in. (meaning don't "speed down" until you are done with all the calculations.)

Comment: Bruce - I will definitely make a point of putting this into CodeReview and adding some For Loops.

Andreas/Aspiring Developer - As YowE3K mentioned, I am running other code in different modules. The code I am running for SpeedUp and SpeedDown are two of these and are only called here. The SpeedUp stops Screen Updating, Events, Calculation, and the Status Bar. Speed Down reactivates this.

As for the second comment Andreas, I actually have a question regarding this. Some code runs when criteria are met, but others are called by buttons. Would that change the criteria you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice this in your extensive code, but have you tried turning off some of Excel's services.

Place start of code:

```
With Excel.Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
   .DisplayStatusBar = False
End With
```

Place at end of code:

```
With Excel.Application
    .DisplayStatusBar = True
    .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: Hello, I apologize for not clarifying this earlier. I have some other codes in other modules and these codes are in that section. These codes you mentioned are being referenced here as the SpeedUp and SpeedDown functions

Comment: I didn't really thoroughly study your code but I saw there some 'main procedures' (at the end!) like ResetSalesHistory that were calling several sub procedures. If that is the way your code mainly works and those SpeedUp and SpeedDown are separately in each sub procedure it means calling and setting those environment variables back and forth.

Might be a tiny bit speedier to do those only once each time.

Comment: @Antti Kivivalli - That definitely sounds like it would make sense. The only issue I see with that is that those reset formulas are all called by buttons while the other functions work when the user inputs something. Would removing the SpeedUp and SpeedDown functions in the regular code not make everything run slower?

Comment: Yes @MikeWinning, like I said that I didn't study the structure of sub procedures. The only point was that if those SpeedUp/Down would be called several times back and forth that wouldn't be useful.

If the other procedures are called by Worksheet Change etc. events so in that event there could be the SpeedUp/Down one time each, but as I wrote, I can't tell. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have quite many lines like this:

```
.Range("D15:W15").formula = strformula(7)
.Range("D15:W15").FillRight
```

When you are already placing the formula to those cells, the FillRight does nothing so can be removed. Probably helps more with the number of lines than speed. :-)

Comment: Really? I did not know that. While it may not speed up my code, it will definitely make it look a lot nicer. Thank you for the advice!